# Are enchantments beyond Protection 10 effective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I've been playing on a full PvP rank up server running Minecraft version 1.5.2, and the maximum enchantment level available there is 25. However, I didn't notice any change between Protection 10 and 25.

Are enchantment levels beyond 10 any more effective than 10?

Answer (score 2):

###No, Protection type enchantments are capped, and the cap is fairly low.

Damage reduction based on Armor and Armor Enchantments has some peculiar mechanics which are detailed on the Minecraft Wiki page for [Armor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Enchantments)<sup>1</sup> (some emphasis mine).

> Each protection enchantment protects against specific types of damage. The amount of damage reduction depends on the **Enchantment Protection Factor** (EPF) provided by that enchantment.

> [...]

> The EPFs for each enchantment and level are the result of the
> following formula:
>
> ```
> floor ( (6 + level^2) * TypeModifier / 3 )
> ```
>
> When a player or mob wearing armor is subjected to damage, **the EPFs of
> all applicable enchantments are added together, capped at 25**,
> multiplied by a random value between 50% and 100%, rounded up, and
> capped again at 20. The damage is then reduced by 4% per point of
> total effective EPF (for example, a total effective EPF of 20 reduces
> damage by 80%).

The "TypeModifier" in the equation depends on the enchantment itself, and is 0.75 for Protection, 1.25 for Fire Protection, 1.5 for Blast and Projectile Protection and 2.5 for Feather Falling.

Note how the EPF is capped twice. We can't do anything about the random number multiplication and the subsequent second cap, but we can make sure to have an EPF of at least 25, to ensure maximum Protection. Using the above formula, we can calculate the EPF for a single armor piece with a certain Protection enchantment level.

```
level |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | ...
EPF   |  1 |  2 |  3 |  5 |  7 | 10 | 13 | 17 | 21 | 26 | 31 | ...
```

From this table, it is immediately evident that you can reach the EPF cap with a single Protection X enchantment. Anything beyond Protection X has no effect on the game mechanics.

Using a full set of armor, and optimizing for lower enchantment levels, you can reach cap with 3 Protection V and 1 Protection IV enchantment (3*7+5=26).

---

<sup>1 This part of the page has been roughly the same in [March 2013](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Armor&oldid=463275), when 1.5 was released.</sup>

Comment: Are there any known plugins that remove this cap?

Comment: @user120350 If any exist, they have to change the entire system, since normally, the effective EPF (the one capped at 20) reduces damage by a flat 4%, meaning an effective EPF of 25 makes you straight-up *immune* to at least direct damage. There are no diminishing returns.

Comment: Do this rule applies to all of the most recent versions?

Comment: @MrLemon and if Mojang was not careful, a EPF over 25 could even heal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the EPFs of an Armour Set, you must first add then and then round them. You actually only need 2 Protection IV and 2 Protection V, because:

```
Protection IV EPF = ((6+4^2)*0.75/3) = 5.5 
Protection V EPF = ((6+5^2)*0.75/3) = 7.75
```

So 5.5+5.5+7.75+7.75=26.5 which is above the 25 cap and should provide maximum protection.

Comment: Please do not repost your [deleted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322570/75275). Try earning some reputation on the site (by asking a good question or answering a question) before you post something that's a comment.